# ProfilePictureView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-layout, android-activity

My application unexpectedly crashes when the below activity is launched. Essentially In this activity users are able to upload their picture from Facebook, and where their profile picture gets cast to an imageview.

I have included below the log cat message:

```
10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1799
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.ProfileCreation}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.dooba.beta.ProfileCreation.onCreate(ProfileCreation.java:87)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    10-17 03:59:52.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     ... 11 more
```

Below is the activity code:

```
public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
FrameLayout layout;
Button save;

protected Number age;

private static final String TAG = "ProfileCreation";

protected Button mConfirm;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);

    RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main); 

    v.requestFocus();

    Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "DLvq1OqSo87kzEw5j1XNBPKJdXF7dxwRtfEPkxWJ");

    mName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtname);
    mAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtage);
    mHeadline = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtheadline);
    mprofilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
    male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rimale);
    female = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rifemale);
    lmale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlmale);
    lfemale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlfemale);
    seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMinimumAge);
    seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMaximumAge);
    seekBarDistance = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarDistance);
    seekBarActivityDistance = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarActivityDistance);


    mConfirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
    mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String name = mName.getText().toString();
        //    Number age = mAge.getText(;
            String headline = mHeadline.getText().toString();






         // age = ((String) age).trim();
            name = name.trim();
            headline = headline.trim();

            if (name.isEmpty() || headline.isEmpty()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else {
                // create the new user!
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();





                if(male.isChecked())
                    gender = "Male";
                else
                    gender = "Female";

                if(lmale.isChecked())
                    lgender = "Male";
                else
                    lgender = "Female";
                age = Integer.parseInt(mAge.getText().toString());




                /* This is the section where the images is converted, saved, and uploaded. I have not been able Locate the image from the ImageView, where the user uploads the picture to imageview from either their gallery and later on from facebook */ 
                ImageView myImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);



                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myImgView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                // Convert it to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

                // Create the ParseFile
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile("profilePicture.png", image);
                // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                file.saveInBackground();



                // Create a column named "Profile Picture" and set the string
                currentUser.put("ImageName", "Profile Picture");

                // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
                currentUser.put("ProfilePicture", file);




                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, MoodActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_message)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });



    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarDistance);
    final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvseekBarDistanceValue);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

    }); // Add this

    Button mcancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    mcancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ProfileCreation.this.startActivity(new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });

    SeekBar seekBarActivity = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarActivityDistance);
    final TextView seekBarActivityValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvseekBarActivityDistanceValue);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

    }); // Add this






    SeekBar seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMinimumAge);
    final TextView txtMinimum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMinAge);

    seekBarMinimum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
             if (progress <= 18) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(18);
                } else {
                    txtMinimum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                }


        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

    }); // Add this

    SeekBar seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMaximumAge);
    final TextView txtMaximum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMaxAge);

    seekBarMaximum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            txtMaximum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

    }); // Add this







    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });


    final ProfilePictureView mprofilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFacebookUpload); 
    authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                        Exception exception) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());
                        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                            Response response) {
                                        if (user != null) {
        mprofilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());

                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                }
    });

} 



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }

    }

    private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] data = null;
        File file = new File(path);
        InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                file));
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
        int bytes_read;
        while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
        }
        input_stream.close();
        return buffer.toByteArray();

    }
```

}

below is the layout code:

```
    <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnFacebookUpload"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border_image"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`ProfilePictureView` extends `FrameLayout` not `ImageView`. This why you are getting the `ClassCastException`. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/ProfilePictureView/) you can find the documentation

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView profilePicture ;
mprofilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
```

replace with

```
ProfilePictureView mprofilePicture;

mprofilePicture = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
```

and import this

```
import com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView;
```

Comment: thank you so much, but then i recieve the error for these lines  ProfilePictureView mprofilePicture;

            mprofilePicture = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
            mprofilePicture.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));  The method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) from the type ProfilePictureView is not visible

Comment: mprofilePicture.setCropped(true);
        mprofilePicture.setProfileId(user.getId());

Do your bitmap function after this

Comment: thank you dhina for your help. In the application user can upload their picture from either facebook or from their phone device gallery. Intially I was using imageview, but had to use ProfilePictureView for facebook, but then can't use that for device gallery which why i got the following error "he method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) from the type ProfilePictureView is not visiblev" so in the new suggestion you propose  mprofilePicture.setProfileId(user.getId()); , would this be setting the profile picture from facebook of the user, because this part is meant to upload picture from user device

Comment: try having a switch case then.. if its in gallery use your bitmap. if it is from Fb just use the method in my prev comment..

Comment: sorry if this is too much too ask, but would it be possible that you could kindly assist me with that>